# How does the interface OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback work?

Tags: android, interface, permissions

if onRequestPermissionsResult needs to be called after requestpermissions, then why doesn't android studio force you into calling  onRequestPermissionsResult, like other interfaces do?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*You* do not call `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, any more than you call `onCreate()` or `onSaveInstanceState()`. The *framework* calls `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, after you call `requestPermissions()` and, more importantly, after the user has dealt with the permission dialog that appears.

Beyond that:

- `onRequestPermissionsResult()` is not an interface, nor is it a member of an interface
- No IDE forces you to call methods on an interface, because Java does not force you to call methods on an interface

Comment: In the title he references [OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html), which is an interface from the Support Library. But it seems like you shouldn't use that directly anyway. It is implemented by AppCompatActivity and AppCompatFragment though.

Comment: @RobCo: Ah, sorry, I missed that. Thanks for pointing it out!